# Leer linea de archivo de texto con formato fijo

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

No estoy seguro cual es la mejor forma de leer El siguiente archivo de texto el cual se genero de la siguiente forma :

```
Struct
int nro_orden;
char desc[30];
int cantidad;





fprintf(pf,"%03d%-30s%03d\n",pedido[i].nro_orden,pedido[i].desc,pedido[i].cantidad);

001Alpargatas                    050

002Zapatillas Nike               020

003Calzones                      040

004Medias levis                  025

005Chomba Adidas                 030
```

Al archivo lo estoy leyendo de la siguiente manera :

```
char string[38];

while(fgets(string,sizeof(string),pf))
{
    sscanf(string,"%03d%29[^\n]%03d",&pedido[i].nro_orden,pedido[i].desc,&pedido[i].cantidad);

}
```

Pero el problema es que pedido[i].desc me queda la descripcion + los blancos. No se si hay una forma de obtener esta descricion sin estos o si los tengo que sacar luego de obtenerlos.

Mucas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! El código que nos traes _probablemente_ no compila... ¿Qué tal si nos ayudas a ayudarte con un buen [mcve] y algún ejemplo de la entrada correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se leen cadenas en Lenguaje C con **`scanf`** el formato **`%s`** solo lee hasta el primer espacio en blanco, otro formato es **`%[regex]`** donde **`regex`** es una expresión regular hasta donde leerá **`scanf`** si dicha expresión se cumple.

Por lo tanto:

**`%[^\n]`** especifica que leerá hasta que la entrada sea un salto de linea
**`%[^0-9]`** especifica que leerà hasta que la entrada sea un dígito de 0 a 9
**`%[regex]`** cualquier otra expresión que se te ocurra

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int nro_orden;
    char desc[30];
    int cantidad;
} pedido_t;

int main()
{
    // Escribiendo los datos
    {
        FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
        pedido_t pedido[5] = 
        {
            { 1, "Alpargatas",      50 },
            { 2, "Zapatillas Nike", 20 },
            { 3, "Calzones",        40 },
            { 4, "Medias levis",    25 },
            { 5, "Chomba Adidas",   30 }
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%03d%-30s%03d\n",
                pedido[i].nro_orden,
                pedido[i].desc,
                pedido[i].cantidad);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    // Leyendo los datos
    {
        FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        pedido_t pedido;

        while(!feof(file))
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d%[^0-9]%d", 
                &pedido.nro_orden,
                 pedido.desc,
                &pedido.cantidad);

            printf("%03d %-30s %03d\n",
                pedido.nro_orden,
                pedido.desc,
                pedido.cantidad);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) no soporta RegEx ¿estás hablando de una librería?

Answer (score 0):

La solucion de la respuesta mas arriba es correcta. Salvo que los espacios se almacenan de manera innecesaria para algunos casos. 
Lo único que agregaría seria una función que elimine los espacios de mas de una cadena de caracteres.

Una forma de hacer esta funcion seria:

```
void eliminar_espacios(char cad[]){
  int i=strlen(cad)-1;
    while(cad[i]==' '){
        cad[i]='\0';
        i--;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva, cualquier duda consultame sin problemas